# Travelling to Saudi for Umrah, my parents are there too. How should I make the niyah?

Tags: umrah

I have a doubt, my parents are already in Mecca (they came from India for Umrah) and I am travelling from London to Saudi for Umrah and meet my parents. I have a connecting flight at Beirut so some people advised me to put Ihram from Beirut airport, However, some people told me I can also go to my parents straight without Ihram state, get fresh, put Ihram, go to Ayesha's mosque, and do the Niyyah from there. Is this permissible? Which way is better?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [fatwa from IslamWeb](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=21184) you are not allowed to enter Mecca unless you were a Muhrim (Made the Niyah earlier and wore the ihram). Those living there are an exception.

If you just finished your Umrah. That's when you can go to Aisha's mosque (also called Tana'eem mosque) and redo your Ihram.

Hence, **if you are going directly to mecca, then you should put the ihram in Beirut**. Or you can try other methods *(i.e:* *go to Madinah first, wear the Ihram, and got Mecca, etc.)*

---

**Note:** it is Mustahab (better) if you take a shower (wash whole body + ear and any areas that water can't reach) and put some perfume before wearing the ihram as the Prophet (PBUH) did once:T

> Zaid bin Thabit (RAA) narrated, ‘When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) intended to make Ihram for Hajj, he would wash, and take off his ordinary clothes (and put on his white Ihram)."

[Related by At-Tirmidhi who declared it to be Hadith-Hasan - sunnah.com](http://sunnah.com/bulugh/6/23)

Answer (score 1):

```
           In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful
```

**According to my researches, it is not necessary for you to take trip to Mecca with Ihram (pilgrim's specific garb). In other words, Miqat is the place which Hojjaj wear their Ihrams (for Umrah Tamato’). It consists of five places (from the perspective of Shia Islam):**

> 1: The mosque of Shajarah
>
> 2: Waadi al Aqiq
>
> 3: Qarn al Manaazel
>
> 4: Yalmalam
>
> 5: Johfe

Eventually, whoever goes from another way (except the mentioned routes), hence he/she ought to wear his/her Ihram from Mahazat Miqat. Therefore with respect to the mentioned items, it denotes that you should not to wear your Ihram from you country. (As you mentioned that “some people told me I can also go to my parents straight without Ihram state” …)

---

**Reference:**

- [library.tebyan.net](http://library.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=102834&ParentID=0&BookID=6856&MetaDataID=10447&Volume=1&PageIndex=6&PersonalID=0&NavigateMode=CommonLibrary&Content=)