# Umrah related-particularly Ihraam

Tags: sharia, sunnah, umrah

We traveled from Medina where we stayed for 2 days. We drove to Mecca for performing our umrah. On the way on inquiring about ihraam and meeqat (for our first umrah) we were advised by our taxi driver a Muslim, that we could settle down in our hotel n since we were performing umrah on the next night we could wear our ihraam from the hotel and proceed to Masjid 'Ayesha and take out neeyat of umrah from there, which is exactly what we did. I would like to know if our umrah is valid or not. And in case we have erred how do we ask for forgiveness and compensate for  the  LAPSE.

Comment: Some more or less relevant posts : http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12070/wearing-ihram-from-masjid-ayesha http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13252/travelling-to-saudi-for-umrah-my-parents-are-there-too-how-should-i-make-the-n http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23702/wearing-ihram-from-masjid-e-aisha-while-comming-from-madina-to-perform-umrah/29878#29878